# Transition from one view to another SwiftUI

Tags: view, segue, swiftui

How can I transition from one `View` to another? Is there push / pop like in UIKit? Do I have to use a `NavigationView` and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

#### Using a `NavigationView`

`NavigationView`s are tied to `NavigationButton` (AFAIK that is the only way to trigger a segue). Here is a simple example where the main view can transition to a detail view.

```
struct DetailView : View {
    let value: String

    var body : some View {
        Text("Full View: \(value)")
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationButton(destination: DetailView(value: "Hello World"),
                             label: { Text("Click Me") })
        }
    }
}
```

This will automatically handle transitions and add a back button.

#### Using State

Another approach is to use a stateful variable to determine if the child view is displayed. Here is another simple example:

```
struct DetailView : View {
    let value: String
    let onDone: () -> Void

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Full View: \(value)")
            Button(action: onDone, label: { Text("Back") })
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @State var displaySubview = false

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            if displaySubview {
                DetailView(value: "Hello World") {
                    self.displaySubview = false
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.displaySubview = true
                }, label: { Text("Click Me") })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach requires you to implement more of the UI elements, but it also allows for more control over views.

Comment: "This is the only way to trigger a segue" ? Meaning you can no longer declare a segue from a button to a different view ? YOu must use a navigation controller??

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
struct ContentView : View {
var body : some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), label: { Text("To Detail")})
    }
}}
```